# PowerPoint: Placeholder doesn't saves its horitzontal text orientation

Tags: powerpoint

When I change the text orientation of a placeholder from left to right in the slide master, save the pptx-file and close the slide master view, the text orientation isn't saved. Which means, when I create a new slide with the changed layout, the text orientation of the placeholder is still left, rather than right. But when I go to the slide master view again, the text orientation is right as I defined bevor. Besides, every other formatting is saved correctly.
I have searched a lot to fix it but cannot find any solution. Is there anybody how knows how to handle the problem?

Placeholder in the master slide:
[image: Placeholder in the master slide]

Placeholder when creating a new slide with the layout:
[image: Placeholder when creating a new slide with the layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out the title placeholder breaks sometimes. Therefore if it is broken, formatting isn't saved.
This workaround helps to fix that issue:

1. Create a new textbox ind the slide master and apply all formatting settings from the title placeholder to that textbox. Make sure, that you do not copy the formatting with the *'copy formatting'* tool. Unfortunately, you have to do it manually.

[image: Do not use copy formatting tool]

2. Deselect the title checkbox in the slide master.The title placeholder disappears then.

[image: Deselect title checkbox]

3. Select the title checkbox again. A new standard title placeholder is created.
4. Then apply the formatting setting to the new title placeholder again from the textbox you created in the first step.
5. Delete the textbox you created in the first step. Then you're done.